# Why is the screen is flickering when I use turtle write method?

Tags: python, python-3.5, turtle-graphics

I am writing a simple ball bouncing simulation using python's turtle library. I run into trouble that the screen is flickering when I use turtle's write method (the flickers happen when I uncomment the comments). Can somebody explain why my code behave like this and how to solve this problem? Thank you so much.

```
    def draw(self):
        turtle.clear()

        width, height = self.size

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(-width//2, height//2)
        turtle.pendown()

        turtle.goto(width//2, height//2)
        turtle.goto(width//2, -height//2)
        turtle.goto(-width//2, -height//2)
        turtle.goto(-width//2, height//2)

        # hours_text = "Hours " + str(self.hours)
        # turtle.write(hours_text, False)

        # turtle.penup()

        # turtle.goto(0, height//2)
        # infections_text = "Infected " + str(self.count_infected())
        # turtle.write(infections_text, False)

        for person in self.people:
            person.draw()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve] so someone can help. It's not self-evident what `self.size` and `self.people` are, for example, and there are no imports here.

Comment: Maybe I could just upload the whole source code? I know it's a little bit hard to gain some context from the code I gave.

Comment: Sure, but please note the word "minimal" in the above link. The idea is to upload code that reproduces the problem, but isn't crowded by extraneous boilerplate or anything unrelated to the problem. In other words, if your source is hundreds of lines, likely that's going to take significant pruning efforts before it's in a suitable state for posting.

Comment: would you need to put the pen down again after the last goto?